# How to rotate a div like 8 ball

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to rotate a rounded div like 8 ball. Just like 8 ball there is a number inside this div with background white. How a ball rotates, like that this div should rotate with a button click. Also, the number should change when rotates.

I have done with my idea but fails, it works only when reloading and the rotation is not proper and I don't know how to change the number also.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.eight-ball {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgb(33, 139, 220);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(33, 139, 220, 1) 0%, rgba(14, 92, 154, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(33, 139, 220, 1) 0%, rgba(14, 92, 154, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(33, 139, 220, 1) 0%, rgba(14, 92, 154, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#218bdc', endColorstr='#0e5c9a', GradientType=0);
}

.eight-ball-inner-white {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  background: rgb(224, 235, 245);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224, 235, 245, 1) 0%, rgba(190, 205, 214, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224, 235, 245, 1) 0%, rgba(190, 205, 214, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(224, 235, 245, 1) 0%, rgba(190, 205, 214, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e0ebf5', endColorstr='#becdd6', GradientType=0);
}

.eight-ball-inner-white span {
  color: #222b32;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 152px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(16deg);
}

.rotate-ball {
  -webkit-animation: rotate-ball linear 2s;
  -moz-animation: rotate-ball linear 2s;
  -ms-animation: rotate-ball linear 2s;
  -o-animation: rotate-ball linear 2s;
  animation: rotate-ball linear 2s;
}

.rotate-ball .spin-ball {
  -webkit-animation: ballspin linear 2s;
  -moz-animation: ballspin linear 2s;
  -ms-animation: ballspin linear 2s;
  -o-animation: ballspin linear 2s;
  animation: ballspin linear 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ballspin {
  0% {
    left: 6px;
    top: 30px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 170%;
    top: 150px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 6%;
    top: 30px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate-ball {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(120deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(220deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="eight-ball rotate-ball">
  <div class="eight-ball-inner-white spin-ball">
    <span>88</span>
  </div>
</div>

<button>Generate Ball</button>
```

Comment: What's your goal? Should the ball rotate sideways or "roll"? Which number should appear on click?

Comment: My Goal is to animate from left to right of inner white color div and comes back to normal position. Any number can come from 1 - 90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $(function(){
  $('#genBall').on("click", function () {
   $('.eight-ball').addClass("rotate-ball");
    setTimeout(RemoveClass, 1200);
   });
   function RemoveClass() {
    $('.eight-ball').removeClass("rotate-ball");
   }
  });
```

```css
.eight-ball {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #1f84d0;
 display: inline-table;
 transition: all ease 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.eight-ball:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-137deg);
    box-shadow: inset 50px 0 70px 6px rgb(0, 0, 0),
    inset -3px 0 6px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.eight-ball-inner-white {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all ease 0.5s;
    background: rgb(224,235,245);
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform: translate(6px,30px);
    /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 27px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);*/
 -webkit-animation: firstrotate ease-in 3s;
    -moz-animation: firstrotate ease-in 3s;
    -ms-animation: firstrotate ease-in 3s;
    -o-animation: firstrotate ease-in 3s;
    animation: firstrotate ease-in 3s;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224,235,245,1) 0%, rgba(190,205,214,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224,235,245,1) 0%,rgba(190,205,214,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(224,235,245,1) 0%,rgba(190,205,214,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e0ebf5', endColorstr='#becdd6',GradientType=0 );
}

.rotate-ball .spin-ball {
 -webkit-animation: ballanim linear 4s;
    -moz-animation: ballanim linear 4s;
    -ms-animation: ballanim linear 4s;
    -o-animation: ballanim linear 4s;
    animation: ballanim linear 4s;
}

@keyframes ballanim {
 0%   {transform: translate(6px,30px) scale(1) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg); width: 400px;}
 50%  {transform: translate(250%,30px) scale(0.3) rotateY(-60deg) rotateX(-5deg) ; width: 200px;}
    100% {transform: translate(300%,30px) scale(0.2) rotateY(-60deg) rotateX(-5deg) ; width: 200px}
}

@-webkit-keyframes ballanim {
 0%   {transform: translate(6px,30px) scale(1) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); width: 400px;}
 50%  {transform: translate(250%,30px) scale(0.3) rotateY(-60deg) rotateX(-5deg) skew(-10deg, -10deg); width: 200px;}
    100% {transform: translate(300%,30px) scale(0.2) rotateY(-60deg) rotateX(-5deg) skew(-10deg, -10deg); width: 200px;}
}




@keyframes firstrotate {
 0%   {transform: translate(-100%,30px) scale(0.3) rotateY(-80deg); width: 250px;}
 50%  {transform: translate(6px,30px) scale(1)   rotateY(0deg); width: 400px;}
    100% {transform: translate(6px,30px) scale(1)   rotateY(0deg); width: 400px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes firstrotate {
 0%   {transform: translate(-100%,30px) scale(0.3) rotateY(-80deg); width: 250px;}
 50%  {transform: translate(6px,30px) scale(1)   rotateY(0deg); width: 400px;}
    100% {transform: translate(6px,30px) scale(1)   rotateY(0deg); width: 400px;}
}

.eight-ball-inner-white span {
    color: #222b32;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 152px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(10deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="eight-ball">
    <div class="eight-ball-inner-white spin-ball">
        <span>GO</span>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="genBall">Rotate</button>
```

Comment: Finally i have done it. If anyone can do better than this please answer.